# How do I fix virtualenv install?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I installed virtualenv using `pip install virtualenv`. Here is my terminal output on trying to check for the installation

```
virtualenv --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.11.6
```

I currently have Python 2.7 running.

Comment: try to check output of `which python` and `which pip`

Comment: Try maybe uninstall and then install again? `sudo pip uninstall virtualenv` and `sudo pip install virtualenv`.

Comment: @Compadre both pip and python are installed in `/usr/local/bin

Comment: This is likely a permission issue. I would recommend that you first uninstall virtualenv, then `brew install python`. This will install python2.7 in `usr/local/bin/`.  Run `brew linkapps`. You can then go ahead to install `virtualenv`.

Comment: @AvihooMamka tried, didn't work

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thank you so much it worked like magic! Since I'm fairly new, I'm guessing that Homebrew installs python to a different Location, since I found out that I have a Python 2.7 in `Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/` that has pip installed in `site.packages`